# Grouping Async calls in function in node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I am new to Node.js. I like the async approach in Node.js. However, I need a synchronous operation right now. I've been looking at the async module. However, I'm stumped on one thing. Please bear in mind, my async call is setup like this:

```
async.parallel(
  [
    operation1,
    operation2
  ],  function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Success!');
    }
  });

  var operation2 = function(callback) {
    console.log('Querying accounts...');
for (var dbNumber=0; dbNumber<100; dbNumber++) {
      var dbName = 'db_' + dbNumber;
      // query database
    }
  };
```

I need to run a query across several of my databases. When all of those queryies are finished, I consider operation2 as complete. The query process is asynchronous itself. For that reason, I'm not sure syntactically how to setup operation2 such that it returns back after all of the asynchronous calls are made to all 100 databases.

How do I do this?

Comment: Not sure by what you mean "When all of those queryies are finished, I consider operation2 as complete."
Anyway, you pretty much have the syntax right there, you just call the callback provided by async when your query returns, so call the async callback inside the query's callback and you should be good to go I think.

Comment: My problem is, the database query runs asynchronously. And it will run 100 times. For that reason, I don't know when to call the callback. How do I call the callback after the database query has executed all 100 times? Due to the async nature, they could finish at different times.

Comment: Ah, I think you may be using the wrong async function(common problem).  It appears you have an array of db names, iterate over it with [async.each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) and callback inside the queries callbacks.  The second function given in the `each` function will not fire till they are all done.

Comment: Ok, just double checked myself and I think `async.each` is the way to go for this.